# iPad - html file input from external drive

Tags: html, ipad

I have an html page with the "file input" on it. Now when I browse it through the iPad, and click on the file input, I get two options,
1. Take Photo or Video
2. Choose Existing

I select "Choose Exising", and it selects the content of the "Photos" directory.

Do any of you know how to change this location to an external drive? I am using i-FlashDrive HD by PhotoFast and need to import some shape files from it to a map application.

I don't want to store the files on the iPad, I want to access them directly from the i-FlashDrive.

Answer (score 0):

The file input only has access to the Camera and Camera Roll, and only in iOS 6 and above.