# Enable HTML file input in iPad to choose files from local Dropbox, Google Drive etc

Tags: html, ios, ipad

Is there any way to allow HTML `<input type="file">` to choose files from local Documents, Dropbox, Google Drive etc. Currently my file inputs are allowing to choose from only a few folders like Camera Roll, Videos. It is useless if I want to upload some documents from iPad.

This looks like a restriction imposed by iOS.. based on this answer [iPad - html file input from external drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19142917/ipad-html-file-input-from-external-drive)
But I want to choose from some local folders inside internal memory only. I don't want external drives. Is there any way to do this now? Any workarounds?
That answer is 2 year old. So I'm hopeful that at least local Dropbox, or Google Drive folder can be opened now.

Comment: You can't control the input file, it's managed by the webview. But I think that feature will come on iOS 9, or at least will let you pick files from iCloud. If you consider using cordova, I created a plugin to pick files from document providers, but you will have to use the file transfer plugin to upload the files

Comment: I'm developing a web application. So I think Cordova is not an option for me :( Both Chrome and Safari are showing only Camera roll as options when choosing files.

Comment: Then there is nothing you can do

Comment: Why @Apple why! :-(

Comment: Nowadays, with iOS 11, you can pick files from files app

Comment: Thanks for the update. @jcesarmobile . Please post details as an answer when you can

Comment: There is nothing to explain, the input file type now just works